# Magento-vars.php - Why needed and how it works

Tags: magento2, multistore

I'm a newbie to Magento and I want to understand what is the use of magento-vars.php and when this file will come into action in the lifecycle.

Comment: It might hack file. Might be you need to remove it from  system

Answer (score 1):

I've worked on around 5 Magento 2 projects and had never heard of it.

Turns out it's for configuring multi-site projects on Magento Cloud:

https://devdocs.magento.com/cloud/project/project-multi-sites.html